# Does this sentence sound correct: " I've been encouraged by you to apply for PhD program."?

Tags: formality

I've encouraged by a professor to apply for a PhD program about three months ago. Now I'm trying to send him an email asking him for some advice, but I guess he probably does not remember me. Is this sound weird to write it like this:

"
Dear Professor X,

My name is Y, and I've been encouraged by you to apply for the PhD program. ...
"

Regards

Comment: since you haven't gotten an answer yet, i'm just gonna say that i'm not an English expert, but judging from everything you've written here, your English isn't that good. you should ask someone you know for help :]

Comment: ...nine months ago you encouraged me to...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, the wording does sound odd. It's technically not incorrect, but it's definitely a 'foreign' way to write. This might not be a bad thing, especially if you've already met the professor, and he was clearly impressed with your capabilities regardless of your English. However, as Zac suggested, you may wish to ask a native-speaker friend to check your letter before sending to make sure it's clear.

If I were writing this letter, I would start with introduction, then remind the professor where and when you met before mentioning what you talked about and requesting his help. For example:

Dear Professor X,

My name is [Y]. We met a few weeks ago at the [Z] event in [location], where we discussed the [course name] PhD program and you encouraged me to apply. Thank you for [your advice/the introduction/taking the time to discuss with me/etc].

I'm now considering applying for the course, and I was wondering... [question/request...]

The key parts are: remind him who you are, thank him for his help before, make your request with the option to refer your request to someone else if more appropriate, describe its importance to you so you're not taking his time for granted, thank him in advance for his help.